# Сумма четных элементов ряда Фибоначчи

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, python-2.x, числа-фибоначчи

Помогите в подсчете суммы, не совсем понял как реализовать?

> Найдите сумму всех четных элементов ряда Фибоначчи, которые не
> превышают 500.

Код:

```
n = int()

def fib(n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2:
        return 1

    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)

for i in range(0, 500, 1):
       i = 0   
       if fib(n)%2 == 0:
          i = i +fib(n)

print('summa=', i)
```

Comment: Вас не смущает использование переменной i и как накопителя результата, и как номера члена последовательности?

Comment: `sum(fib(x) for x in range(2, 200, 2))` ?

Comment: @Awesome Man: Рекомендую переписать код fib() так, чтобы вместо рекурсивного подхода применялся итеративный и сделайте функцию генератором, т.е. `yield`.

Comment: @Владимир, в цикле for?

Comment: @AwesomeMan, почитайте [здесь](http://mortada.net/fibonacci-numbers-in-python.html)

Comment: @Awesome Man: 1. Вообще `if` в `for` не нужен!

Comment: @MaxU,почему здесь двойка на шаге(последняя двойка  ,а не единица (2,200,2))?

Comment: @AwesomeMan, пардон не внимательно прочитал условие - я думал вы ищете сумму чисел Фибоначчи __от/для__ четных чисел...

Comment: @AwesomeMan, вы можете дать определение "четному элементу ряда Фибоначчи" - это когда сам элемент четный или когда элемент имеет чётный индекс? И что именно не должно превышать `500` - сумма элементов или сами элементы последовательности Фибоначчи?

Comment: @MaxU, четный елемент ряда Фибоначчи ето тот который четный  не по индексу, тоесть, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ... в первых 10 елементах, 34 будет четным числом.а не его порядковый номер
Вот полное условие задачи.
http://euler.jakumo.org/problems/view/2.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Код из [примера по использованию functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache):

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
```

Пример использования - найдём сумму всех четных элементов ряда Фибоначчи, для первых 500 элементов ряда Фибоначчи:

```
In [41]: sum(fib(n) for n in range(501) if fib(n)%2 == 0)
Out[41]: 69711612280848940069862191435203641975035128293848653632054481474162785811431645345778829438111260647062
```

Скорость работы:

```
In [42]: %timeit sum(fib(n) for n in range(501) if fib(n)%2 == 0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 169 µs per loop
```

Информация о кэше:

```
In [43]: fib.cache_info()
Out[43]: CacheInfo(hits=13765530, misses=501, maxsize=None, currsize=501)
```

PS AFAIK `lru_cache` реализован только для Python **3**.x

**Внимание:** ответ на вопрос автора находится ниже (см. **UPDATE**). Код выше я привел для примера использования и демонстрации эффективности декоратора `lru_cache()`, который, в свою очередь, удобно и по-моему очень эффективно использовать для рекурсивного нахождения большого количества элементов ряда Фибоначчи...

**UPDATE:**

> Найдите сумму всех четных элементов ряда Фибоначчи, которые не
>   превышают четыре миллиона.

```
fib_seq = {}

def fib_iterative(n):
    if n in fib_seq.keys():
        return fib_seq[n]
    a, b, x = 0, 1, n
    while x > 0:
        a, b = b, a + b
        x -= 1
    fib_seq[n] = a
    return a

summ = 0
last_fib = i = 0
while last_fib <= 4000000:
    last_fib = fib_iterative(i)
    if last_fib % 2 == 0:
        summ += last_fib
    i += 1

print(summ)
```

Результат:

```
4613732
```

Comment: стоит отметить, что код в вашем ответе даёт результат отличный от кода в [моём](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612651/23044) и [@VladD](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612575/23044) ответах (188).

Comment: @jfs, это ответ на [задачу Эйлера указанную в комментарии](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612502/%d0%a1%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%87%d0%b8/612518?noredirect=1#comment842766_612502). В ответе я указал - `которые не превышают __четыре миллиона__.`

Comment: `69711612280848940069862191435203641975035128293848653632054481474162785811431645345778829438111260647062` не является ответом ни на вопрос ни на задачу Эйлера. Сам вопрос не содержит задачу Эйлера и уже поздно менять вопрос (из-за существующих ответов--в противном случае следовало бы из комментария в вопрос перенести условие).

Comment: @jfs, именно поэтому в ответе присутствует замечание, выделенное жирным шрифтом

Comment: Как я уже сказал: следует отвечать на вопрос как написан (в качестве *дополнения* можно указать дополнительные решения)—ответ 188 а не что-то другое.

Answer (score 4):

Вот вам решение в O(1) по памяти и O(n) по времени, но на C#. Думаю, должно переноситься один к одному на Python.

```
IEnumerable<long> Fibonacci()
{
    int prev = 0, next = 1;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return prev;
        var oldnext = next;
        next = prev + next;
        prev = oldnext;
    }
}

// ...
var result = Fibonacci().TakeWhile(n => n < 500).Where(n => n % 2 == 0).Sum();
```

---

Кстати, чётными будут те члены ряда Фибоначчи, индекс которых делится на три. (Доказывается в лоб по индукции.)

Comment: Плохое решение - он не на питоне:) Можно уже и питон выучить

`
    a = 1
    b = 1
    s = 0
    while (a < 500):
 (a,b) = (a+b, a)
 if a % 2 == 0:
  s += a
    print s
`

Comment: @KoVadim: Можно выучить, но я вместо этого выучил C# :-P

Comment: @KoVadim я не знаком с C#, но нахожу решение очень читаемым. Хотя так как вопрос имеет метку Python, то следует код именно на Питоне приводить (ответ допустим, если считать C# псевдо-кодом в данном случае). Независимо я на Питоне практически [один в один решение написал](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612651/23044)

Comment: Все таки, лучше не публиковать решения на другом языке, если об этом не упомянуто в вопросе. И я не понимаю, почему такое решение ещё плюсуют.

Comment: @KoVadim, один из тегов этого вопроса - `алгоритм`, а приведенный алгоритм понятен и эффективен.

Comment: Приведенных "алгоритм" использует специфичесое расширение C# (да, в питоне есть подобное, но). И поэтому является  "алгоритмом" с большой натяжкой.

Comment: @KoVadim: А чем генераторы или list comprehension специфичны для C#? Нормальная функциональная фича.

Comment: а я не о них. а  о их реализации. большинству так сходу и не будет понятно, что делает yield и как оно вообще работает. Все таки алгоритм должен описывать последовательность действий, **известных пользователю** для достижения нужного результата. (да, теперь, вместо "последовательность" используют "порядок", но это сильно не портит идею).

Comment: @KoVadim: Исходя из ответа jfs, `yield` нативно доступен в Питоне :-P

Comment: да, я об этом писал. Но это не отменяет того, что данный шарповый код не является нормальным алгоритмом, более того, оверинженирингом.

Comment: @KoVadim: У каждого своё мнение. Мне этот код кажется нормальным, а отделение вычисления последовательности Фибоначчи в отдельную процедуру практически обязательным шагом. У нас, судя по всему, разные взгляды на правильную декомпозицию алгоритмов.

Comment: мы  не обсуджаем декомпозицию. Мы обсуджаем то, что данный код на шарпе плохой в плане обучения.

Comment: @KoVadim: В плане обучения у нас есть исходно бесконечная последовательность Фибоначчи, которую по условию нужно ограничить значениями, не превосходящими 500, выбрать из них чётные, и сложить. _Именно это код и делает._ Мне кажется этот код подходящим с точки зрения дидактики.

Comment: Если посмотреть в соседний тред, то стает понятным, что автор вопроса - начинающий и не понимает yield.

Comment: @KoVadim: Но это ведь не повод снижать стандарты. Если задача естественным образом решается в терминах генераторов, то их надо понять, разобраться и использовать, а не ограничиваться выразительными средствами чистого C. (Замечание в сторону: понять генераторы намного проще, чем сишные строки, по моему ощущению. Высокоуровневые конструкции кажутся мне намного более простыми и логичными.)

Comment: не пытайтесь оправдать себя.

Comment: @KoVadim: И не думал. Я считаю свой ответ хорошим и правильным.

Answer (score 3):

Так как 500 это небольшое число,  то можно использовать простое итеративное определение, чтобы сгенерировать серию чисел Фибоначчи:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
from itertools import takewhile 

def fib(a=0, b=1):
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a+b

fibs = takewhile(lambda f: f < 500, fib())
print(sum(f for f in fibs if f % 2 == 0)) # sum even
```

Код генерирует все числа Фибоначчи, не превышающие 500 (по значению, не по номеру), и суммирует чётные  (по значению) из них.

Это эквивалентно (всё в кучу) простому алгоритму в лоб:

```
def even_fib(limit, a=0, b=1):
    while a < limit:
        if a % 2 == 0:
            yield a
        a, b = b, a+b

print(sum(even_fib(500)))
```

Оба примера печатают 188.

Стоит заметить,  что в общем случае существуют более [эффективные методы вычисления n-ого числа Фибоначчи (O(log n))](http://ideone.com/36tguL) и в частности вычисление суммы чётных чисел Фибоначчи может быть не дороже [вычисления одного числа Фибоначчи ((F[3*n+2]-1) // 2)](http://ideone.com/MP7ola).

Связанные вопросы:

- [nth fibonacci number in sublinear time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1525521/4279)
- [Closed form for the sum of even fibonacci numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/323058/1665)

Comment: ,я новичек в Питоне, можна ли реализовать подобное через цикл for ?

Comment: спасибо за `takewhile` - это как раз то, чего мне не хватило для красивой реализации...

Comment: @AwesomeMan: код в вопросе—это простейшая итеративная реализация (вполне идиоматичный код для Питона, без извращений). Я не знаю цикла проще чем `while True`. Вероятно вас `yield` смущает. Вам стоит про генераторы, итераторы почитать. `yield` конструкция это одна из вещей, к которой достаточно просто привыкнуть. Попробуйте выполнить [весь код из самого популярного вопроса по Питону (по голосам), чтобы понимание улучшить](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-is-the-function-of-the-yield-keyword). По-хорошому, стоит на русском про yield спросить, если это ещё не сделано.

Comment: `s/код в вопросе/код в ответе/`

Answer (score 2):

```
def fib(n):
    if n==1 or n==2:
        return 1
    return fib( n-1 ) + fib( n-2 )

print( sum(fib(i) for i in range(1, 501) if i%2 == 0) )
```

Comment: Этот код суммирует числа Фибоначчи с чётными *индексами* (а не чётными *значениями*, как [требуется](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/612502/%d0%a1%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d1%80%d1%8f%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%a4%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%87%d0%b8#comment842766_612502)) пока сумма не стала больше 500. Фраза в вопросе: *"которые не превышают 500"* говорит что ответ неверный так как 500 относится к элементам ряда Фибоначчи, а не самой сумме.

Comment: @jfs,Вы правы что по индексу, не доглядел, алгоритм должен суммировать ряд, по значениям елементов ряда , до числа 500, а не сумма должна быть меньше 500, если, я Вас правильно понял, огромное спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

```
def fabionachi(maximum):
    numbers = [1,2]
    i = 1
    while True:
        numbers.append(numbers[i] + numbers[i-1])
        if numbers[i] > int(maximum):
            del numbers[i]
            break
        i += 1
    print ("Колличество элементов: ", len(numbers))
    print ("Сумма все четных чисел: ", (sum(x for x in numbers if x % 2 == 0)))

fabionachi (4000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Я тут с опозданием, но вот:

```
a,b,x,t=1,2,1,0
while a < 4000000:
    x = b -x
    a = a + x
    b = a 
    if x % 2 ==0:
        t += x
        print(str(t)+ " Сумма четных")
```

Что еще может быть проще? :D

Answer (score 0):

А вот такой механизм чем плох?

```
def fib():
    res = 0
    f1, f2 = 0, 1
    even_sum = 0
    while res < 4000000:
        res = f1 + f2
        f1, f2 = f2, res
        if res % 2 == 0:
            even_sum += res
    return even_sum
print(fib())
```

Comment: Это вопрос или ответ?

Comment: Скорее ответ...

Answer (score 0):

Я только начинаю создавать первые программы. Наверное это самое простое решение.

```
f=[]
def fun(n): '''выводим список чисел Фибоначчи'''
  a=0
  f.append(a)
  b=1
  f.append(b)
  print(f)

  for i in range(2,n): #создаем новое число путем сложения двух предыдущих
    c=a+b
    a=b
    b=c
    f.append(c)
  print(f)

  r=0 #Это переменная для записи суммы четных чисел ряда

  for m in f:
    if m % 2 == 0: #проверяем на кратность
        r=r+m
  print(r)

fun(500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что у меня получилось самое странное и нерациональное решение, но я поделюсь им. Если есть предложения или критика ( а она точно должна быть) - милости прошу.

```
ls1 = [1, 2]  # Решил сделать через список (1 и 2 даны, поэтому начало такое)
sum = 0

for i in ls1:  # Пробежимся по списку в последствии дополняя его

    a = ls1[len(ls1) - 2] 
    b = ls1[len(ls1) - 1]
    c = a + b
    ls1.append(c)

    if b > 500:  # В оригинале здесь должно быть 4000000
        break

for x in ls1:
    if x % 2 == 0:
    sum += x

print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня вот так получилось. Возможно кому-то поможет

```
a, b, c, summa = 1, 2, 2, 0
while summa < 4000000:
    a += b
    b, c = c, a
    if a % 2 == 0:
        summa += a
print(summa + 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def calcul(x):
    array = [1, 2]# массив из двух элементов
    numbers = 2 # результат

    while numbers <= x:
        array_3 = array[0] + array[1]
        array.pop(0)
        array.append(array_3)
        numbers += array_3
        if numbers > x:
             numbers -= array_3
             break
    return numbers 


print(calcul(4000000))
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение в 10 строк кода

```
fib = [1, 1]
a, b, sum, i, res = fib[0], fib[1], 0, 2, 0
while sum < 4000000: #сюда ввести до которого числа нужно искать
    sum = a + b
    fib.append(sum)
    i += 1
    a, b = fib[i-1], fib[i-2]
    if sum % 2 == 0:
        res += sum
print(res)
```

И ряд фибоначи в подарок

```
print(fib)
```

(не судите строго я только учусь программировать)