# Переписать рекурсию на цикл: количество последовательностей n-бит без 11

Tags: python, алгоритм, рекурсия

Есть задание
По данному натуральному n определите количество последовательностей длины n из 0 и 1, не содержащих двух единиц подряд.

Есть ответ

```
def seq_count(n, p = 0):
    if not n: return 1
    return seq_count(n - 1, 0) + (0 if p else seq_count(n - 1, 1))
```

Нужно переписать итеративно.

`seq_count(3)` вернет `5`, так как из возможных комбинаций:

```
000 001 011 111 010 100 110 101
```

не содержат 2 единицы подряд:

```
000 001 010 100 101
```

но почему это работает совершенно не понятно, поэтому и прошу переписать на циклы.

Comment: А что за последователи длины? Как работает алгоритм? Почему `seq_count(3)` вернет 5?

Comment: seq_count(3) вернет 5, так как из возможных комбинаций 000 001 011 111 010 100 110  101, не содержат 2 единицы подряд 000 001  010 100 101, но почему это работает совершенно не понятно, поэтому и прошу переписать на циклы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> почему это работает совершенно не понятно, поэтому и прошу переписать на циклы

В данном случае рекурсивное решение  (как это часто бывает для задач динамического программирования) буквально решение описывает: `f(0...) = f(00..) + f(01..)` и `f(1...) = f(10..)` то есть количество последовательностей бит без 11 длиной n равно количеству последовательностей длиной (n-1), начинающихся на 0, плюс количество последовательностей, начинающихся на 1, если предыдущий бит не равен 1 (чтобы исключить 11):

```
def count(n, previous_bit=0):
    assert n>=0
    return 1 if n==0 else (
        count(n-1, 0)
        + (previous_bit == 0) * count(n-1,1))
```

Что почти также ясно как решение в лоб (перебрать все битовые последовательности длиной n бит, посчитать сколько не содержит 11):

```
def brute_force(n):
    return sum(1 for bits in map(bin, range(2**n)) if '11' not in bits)
```

Циклы могут скрыть очевидность правильности решения:

```
def fib(a=0, b=1):
    """Fibonacci sequence"""
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a+b
```

Все варианты одинаковые результаты выдают:

```
for n, f in zip(range(10), fib(1, 2)):
    print(n, count(n), f, brute_force(n))
```

Результат:

```
0 1 1 1
1 2 2 2
2 3 3 3
3 5 5 5
4 8 8 8
5 13 13 13
6 21 21 21
7 34 34 34
8 55 55 55
9 89 89 89
```

Добавив `@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=5)` перед `count()`, можно запомнить несколько предыдущих результатов, чтобы не вычислять их повторно.

Если точный результат не нужен (достаточно приближённого), то есть замкнутые формулы, которые за O(1) результат позволяют находить.  Подробнее см. ссылки в ответе на [Сумма четных элементов ряда Фибоначчи](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/612651/23044).

Answer (score 2):

Можно повторить генерацию комбинаций и посчитать те, что не имеют двух единиц подряд:

```
import itertools


items = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product('01', repeat=3)]
print(items)  # ['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']

items = [i for i in items if '11' not in i]
print(items)  # ['000', '001', '010', '100', '101']
print(len(items))  # 5
```

Алгоритм есть, теперь можно проверить его:

```
import itertools


def seq_count_v2(n):
    items = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product('01', repeat=n)]
    items = [i for i in items if '11' not in i]
    return len(items)

  
for i in range(3, 10):
    print(seq_count(i), seq_count_v2(i))
```

Совпадает:

```
5 5
8 8
13 13
21 21
34 34
55 55
89 89
```

---

**PS.** Знаю, что алгоритм в `seq_count_v2` не оптимизированный, но решил показать саму идею

Answer (score 1):

Попробуем дать не рыбу, но удочку.

Пусть есть правильная последовательность длиной K. Эта последовательность может кончаться на 0 - тогда к ней можно добавить хоть 0, хоть 1. А если она кончается на 1, то  к ней можно добавить только 0. Или другая интерпретация: 0-последовательность, может быть получена как из более короткой 0-последовательности, так и из более короткой 1-последовательности, а вот 1-последовательность можно сделать только из 0-последовательности.

Обозначим количество первых F0(K), вторых F1(K). Их количество в зависимости от количества последовательностей предыдущей длины:

```
F0(K) = F0(K-1) + F1(K-1)
F1(K) = F0(K-1)
S(K) = F0(K) + F1(K)  //общее количество правильных последовательностей
```

Осталось задать начальные значения для единичной длины и сделать цикл с обновлением значений.

P.S. Получающаяся последовательность содержит довольно примечательные числа